# Run commands inside Docker as non root after running it with exec (shell)

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu

I have a Django project with Docker (in Ubuntu) and MySQL as a database, everything is working. I'm just curious:

Instead of running the long command like:

```sh
docker-compose run backend python manage.py startapp myapp
# 'backend' is the name of service in docker-compose file
```

I like to open the shell like:

```
docker-compose run backend sh
```

And then run my command:

```
python manage.py startapp myapp
```

But in this case it will be created by root, so I can't modify/save from the outside, (permissions required)

I solve this with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .
```

But I'm curious if there is any other ways, so that I could run the exec and modify my file from inside as non-root, instead of changing the owner every time.

docker-compose:

```
    version: '3.9'
    services:
        backend:
            build: .
            volumes: 
                - .:/backend
            ports: 
                - 8000:8000   
            depends_on: 
                - db
        db:
            image: mysql:latest
            environment:
                MYSQL_DATABASE: 'pass'
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pass'
            volumes:
            - ./data/mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3.9
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    WORKDIR /backend
    COPY requirements.txt backend/requirements.txt
    RUN pip install -r backend/requirements.txt
    COPY . /backend
    CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Instead of trying to use Docker for day-to-day development, can you use a Python virtual environment?  And then when you deploy, remove the `volumes:` block that overwrites the `/backend` directory, so that you're using the (integration-tested) copy of the code from the image?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but i found a way of resolving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer, simply to add a user in the docker file with these lines at the end of dockerfile (backend directory):

```
RUN adduser myuser
USER myuser
```

if workin with Django rest framework and React, add this line at the enf of dockerfile(front end directory)

```
USER node
```

as i found out that, all the official Node.js images have a Linux user added in the upstream image called node.

and now it is possible to modify the same file from outside or inside without permissions restrictions